# Wordpress 'pre_get_posts' not working on ajax?

Tags: wordpress

Im using a plugin to select featured post which uses 'pre_get_posts' to filter posts.It works fine in normal query_post() but it is not working inside ajax. Here is my code

```
<?php 
add_action('wp_ajax_portscroll', 'portscroll');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_portscroll', 'portscroll');

function portscroll(){

?>
<?php                   
                        $offset_click= $_POST['data'];


                        $offset= 4+$offset_click*2; 
                        $args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'portfolio',
                            'posts_per_page' => 2,
                            'featured' => 'yes',
                            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                            'order' => 'ASC',
                            'offset'=> $offset
                        );
                        $post_osrtfolios = query_posts($args);

                        if ($post_osrtfolios) :
                            foreach ($post_osrtfolios as $post_osrtfolio) :
                            ///contents goes here
                            endforeach;
                        endif;
            wp_reset_query();                       
    } ?>
```

Everything works fine, query works fine but the parameter 'featured' => 'yes' is not working. This parameter is from [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-post/).

Comment: where is your applied code..?

Answer (score -1):

```
$args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'portfolio',
                            'posts_per_page' => 2,
                           'meta_query' => array(
                                array(
                                    'key' => '_is_featured',
                                    'value' => 'yes'
                                )
                            ),
                            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                            'order' => 'ASC',
                            'offset'=> $offset
                        );
```

Use this